# How to set small expander header and widen the content in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expander

I'm creating a custom virtual keyboard. Currently, for all punctuation, I set it on another Grid. Expander content seems can hold the punctuation view. But currently it need to set the size of the content if I want the expander content to be able to view the content inside.

How do I make to be able to have button size expander and when click, the content will be expanding to it's wider size?

[image: OSK]

How to make expander are size as below image (yellow rectangle) but when click on the expander, the content will be expand like GIF?

[image]

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52.25" Margin="0,238.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168.187" Background="#FF3C3C3C" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="18" BorderBrush="#FF6E6E6E">
    <Expander Header="?!#" ExpandDirection="Up" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <!-- How add content grid which can be expander at full while maintaining the expander header to small size? -->
    </Expander>
</Button>
```

Comment: Why do you want to squeeze the whole thing into one `Button`? I suggest you would rather put a `ToggleButton` in the Keyboard and a seperate `Expander` somewhere else (bottom?) + bind the `IsExpanded` Property to the `IsChecked` Property of the `ToggleButton`.

Comment: @LittleBit I'm not so much explore in WPF yet. My knowledge about what can be done, what should be done, what shouldn't be done is limited. I would like to try anything on suggestion so I know something. Btw, does you mean by the `IsExpanded` property is binding to element `ToogleButton` trigger from button "Punctuation_Clicked"?

Comment: Well, you could handle it via code, but i'd suggest you to handle it in the `XAML` (in my opinion, it is much easier). I'll provide you a simple example as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to put the `Button`s of the extended Keyboard in another `Panel` and control the `Visibility` of the `Panel` with a `ToggleButton`.

When you use an `Expander` (as you did) to hold the extended Keyboard this can be easily done similar to this:

```
<Grid Background="Gray" Height="300">
    <!-- Basic Keyboard Buttons can be placed here -->
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Put some Buttons from the BASIC Keyboard here"/>
    <!-- Button to bring the extanded Keyboard into view -->
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ExtendedKeyboardActive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="?!#" Width="50"/>
    <!-- Extended Keyboard (Note: I would rather use a simple <Grid/> instead of an <Expander/> but it is up to you)-->
    <Expander VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ExpandDirection="Up" IsExpanded="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ExtendedKeyboardActive}" Background="LightGray">
        <Grid Height="300">
            <!-- Content of the extaned Keyboard -->
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Put some Buttons from the EXTENDED Keyboard here"/>
            <!-- Button ti hide the extended Keyboard (optional if it the 'ExtendedKeyboardActive' is not covered over by the extended Keyboard Grid) -->
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ExtendedKeyboardActive}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="ABC" />
        </Grid>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Or you could use a `PopUp`, because the `Expander` has this Arrow-Circle-Thing which is always displayed and not really needed (Thanks @[Bradley Uffner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner)).

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <!-- Basic Keyboard Buttons can be placed here -->
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Put some Buttons from the BASIC Keyboard here"/>
    <!-- Button to bring the extanded Keyboard into view -->
    <ToggleButton x:Name="ExtendedKeyboardActive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="?!#" Width="50"/>
    <!-- Extended Keyboard -->
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ExtendedKeyboardActive}" Placement="Center" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}">
        <Grid Background="LightGray">
            <!-- Content of the extended Keyboard -->
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Put some Buttons from the extended Keyboard here"/>
            <!-- Button to go back to the basic Keyboard -->
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ExtendedKeyboardActive}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="ABC" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Using a `Popup` control instead of a hidden `Grid` would give you the same basic functionality, but with more control over the behaviors, and a few extra features.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Right, i totally forgot the `PopUp`, thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: yep..it's working! I was confuse how to use binding/converters and how do people know how to use it :D

Currently, I place the togglebutton as Hidden on some area. And I handle the click event to show and hide extended. Popup things remains as you suggest.